# Failing to build my project due to Null safety issues in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I have been away from Flutter and Dart for some month now but when I saw that Flutter 2 was released I decided to update one of my Flutter projects. Super cool evertything and I just love Flutter and Dart.

Now I have run in to a null safety issue.

Dart is complaning on a method and I get when building the project.

```
Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'String' doesn't allow null.
```

The method that it complains about

```
static String _fmt(String fmt, Object? val, int maxlen) {

  if (null == val) {
    return '';
  }

  // -- Ad support for thousand separators. --
  if (fmt.startsWith('%,') && fmt.endsWith('d')) {
    int i = val as int;
    val = i.toThousandString(',');
    fmt = '%${fmt.substring(2, fmt.length - 1)}s';
  }
  String s = sprintf(fmt, [val]);

  // -- Truncate if text overflows. --
  if (s.length > maxlen) {
    s = s.substring(0, maxlen);
    if (s.length > 1) {
      return s.substring(0, s.length - 2) + '..';
    } else if (s.length > 0 ) {
      return s.substring(0, s.length - 1) + '.';
    }
  } else {
    return s;
  }
}
```

The code is ugly but except for that I can't see that anything in this method could return null.

Or am I stupid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that not all of your code paths return a value:

```dart
if (s.length > maxlen) {
    s = s.substring(0, maxlen);
    if (s.length > 1) {
      return s.substring(0, s.length - 2) + '..';
    } else if (s.length > 0 ) {
      return s.substring(0, s.length - 1) + '.';
    }

    // Nothing will be explicitly returned if control flow reaches here.

  } else {
    return s;
  }
```

Previously this meant *implicitly* returning `null`.  Add a return value there or adjust your logic so that all possible paths are covered.

(Now, `maxlen` probably is expected to be non-negative, which would make it impossible to hit that control path in practice, but there's no way for the analyzer to know that.)